# Domain Transfer Email Question

Tags: web-hosting, email, transfer

I have a domain name owned by Company A, webhosting and emailhosting package in the hands of Company B, And I want to transfer the webhosting and emails from B to C.

I'm guessing I need to contact A and ask them to set the nameservers to C instead of B.

But how do I make sure that no e-mails get lost? Do i already create the same emails in C? 
Or how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**. Create the same mailboxes at the new host that you have at the old host. If you don't those accounts will no longer exist and new emails will bounce back to the sender

**Step 2**. Change your DNS records to point to your new host

**Step 3**. Due to DNS propagation delays you will still need to check the old host for emails for up to two days. You can't use the domain name any more but you can still use the IP Address to access the mail server.

Comment: Thank you! So I need to contact Company A ( which has the domain name ) to change DNS settings? I thought that you only had to change the nameservers?

Comment: Yes, you just need to change the nameservers.